# Experiment controller using a generic array and method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to find the time it takes for a Bubble sort method of sorting an integer array vs a selection sort.

```
public class ExperimentController
{
    private static int[] intArray = {};
    

     public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      System.out.println("");
      ExperimentController EX = new ExperimentController();

      for(int i =0; i<=300;i=i+50){
          long time = EX.timeBubbleSortPerformance(i, 0);
          System.out.println(time);

        }
        
        
       }
       
    public long timeBubbleSortPerformance(int numberOfItems, int seed){
        
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        RandomStuffContainer RSC = new RandomStuffContainer();
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfItems; i++){
            int randomInt = random.nextInt();
            RSC.addToFront(intArray[randomInt]);   
            RSC.selectionSort(intArray[randomInt]);   

        }
        
        
        
        long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timeTotal = stopTime-startTime;
        return timeTotal;
    }
}
```

The method calls the Random stuff container class for the methods.

```
public class RandomStuffContainer<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
       ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

    public  void main(String[] args){
     ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

        
    }
    
    public void addToFront(T value)
    {
       array.add(0, value);
    }
    
    /**
     * Adds the inputted String i to the back of the Arraylist
     *
     * @param  A generic parameter T
     */
    public void addToBack(T value)
    {
       array.add(value);
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Sorts the Arraylist using selection sort algorithim
     *
     */
    public void selectionSort() 
    {
       for(int i=0; i<array.size() -1; i++)
    {
        int smallestIndex = i;

        for(int j=i+1; j<array.size(); j++)
        {
            if(array.get(smallestIndex).compareTo((array.get(j))) > 0  )
            {
                smallestIndex = j;
            }
        }
        T temp = array.get(i);
        array.add(i,array.get(smallestIndex));
        array.add(smallestIndex, temp);
    } 
}
    

    
    public void bubbleSort(){
         T temp;
         
        if (array.size()>1) // check if the number of orders is larger than 1
        {
            for (int x=0; x<array.size(); x++) // bubble sort outer loop
            {
                for (int i=0; i < array.size()-i; i++) {
                    if (array.get(i).compareTo(array.get(i+1)) > 0)
                    {
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i,array.get(i+1) );
                        array.set(i+1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Copies array list data to String and returns String.
     * Used for testing
     */
    public String toString() {
       {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (T s : array)
        {
            sb.append(s.toString());
            sb.append("\t");
        }      
        return  sb.toString();
    }
 }
}
```

I am trying to use random to randomly fill the array in RandomStuffContainer with ints and then use the sort method to sort that and get the runtime from it. I know my code is messy and sorry for that but any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What shall we imagine under **the runtime from it**? How we can know? :))

Comment: What?  If you are asking about how I am telling the time, that's what the timeTotal is.

Comment: That can only happen if `intArray` has a length of zero.  In such a case, there is nothing to sort, so use `if (intArray.length > 0)` to execute the loop that makes use of RandomStuffContainer only when the array has a positive length.

Answer (score 1):

Enable all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.  The compiler will tell you that you forgot to specify a type in `RandomStuffContainer RSC = new RandomStuffContainer();`.  You probably wanted to do this:

```
RandomStuffContainer<Integer> RSC = new RandomStuffContainer<>();
```

Also, `random.nextInt()` returns a random 32-bit int value.  The returned value is by no means guaranteed to be a valid index in `intArray`.

You’ll want to [limit the value returned:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int))

```
int randomInt = random.nextInt(intArray.length);
```

Look at the `selectionSort` method in RandomStuffContainer.  It does not take any arguments.  So you should not be passing any arguments to it.  Again, the compiler told you this.

You should not call `selectionSort` every time you add something to the RandomStuffContainer.  Give the container all the elements, and *after the loop is done,* call `selectionSort()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't think I can enable all compiler warnings. I'm using BlueJ and the options menu is pretty limited.

Comment: How could I limit it so that the value has to be positive? Otherwise, I get an IllegalArgument Exception that bound must be positive.